# Inject a method to be called inside a reference's method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, logging

Let's imagine the following situation (which I will simplify by pretending to have only the Model and View/Business layer)

I am using Entity Framework and I want to log all the changes into a Log table as JSON.

I have been able to achieve that by overriding the DbContext.SaveChanges() method and reading the ChangeTracker().

Here's an example:

```
public class LogContext : DbContext
{
    public LogContext(string context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var added = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
        var modified = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
        var deleted = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();

        Logger.RecordAdded(added);
        Logger.RecordModified(modified);
        Logger.RecordDeleted(deleted);
    }
}
```

My `RealContext` is going to instantiate this `LogContext` that is going to call my `Logger`.

What If I have 2 projects, one for the Model and another for my View/Business for example and I want to be able to get the Logged user while inside my Logger class, even though the Model layer has no idea which kind of View/Business is calling it (MVC project, Windows Forms, etc..)

The idea I had would be to send a Func<> as parameter and this function would get the user on the View/Business layer (even while being called on the Model), but this would mean to rewrite all the SaveChanges calls to send this function.

I would like to know if there's some way to "inject" this function without needing to rewrite all my SaveChanges throughout the project.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you inject the `Func` or an object which returns the current user in through the `LogContext` constructor?

Comment: @SteveWilkes I'm not very familiar with DI frameworks. But would it be possible to create an DI for a object on my View/Business project to be called inside my Model project (different dlls) while maintaining the Model project "ignorant" about my View/Business one? Do you have any recommendation on a DI framework that would allow me to do that?

Comment: How does your `LogContext` object fit into your overall architecture? Do you new it up in a class within your Model layer? If so how does the class in which you do that get instantiated? [StructureMap](http://docs.structuremap.net) is my DI tool of choice, but you'd need a plan on how to fit it into your architecture...

Comment: @SteveWilkes Thanks a lot! You answered my question. I was so focused on the separation of layers I've forgotten I have to new it on my Business layer (on my UnityOfWork actually) so I'll just have to "wire" the function there.

Comment: Note to self: write stuff in answers, not just comments :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than return a User to the base logger, which would be exposing it to concepts it shouldn't really know about, why not implement a tagging or additional information system?  To extend your existing LogContext:

```
public class LogContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly Func<string> _getAdditionalInfoFunc;
    public LogContext(string context, Func<string> getAdditionalInfoFunc)
        : base(context)
    {
            _getAdditionalInfoFunc = getAdditionalInfoFunc;
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var added = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added).ToList();
        var modified = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
        var deleted = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                    .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Deleted).ToList();

        string extraInfo = _getAdditionalInfoFunc != null
                         ? _getAdditionalInfoFunc()
                         : string.Empty;

        Logger.RecordAdded(added, extraInfo);
        Logger.RecordModified(modified, extraInfo);
        Logger.RecordDeleted(deleted, extraInfo);
    }
}
```

This would be a pretty flexible solution.  You can then have the injector inject a func that returns a string with as much context-relevant information as you need, in a free format.

The benefit of this over injecting different implementations depending on the location of the class that needs it is that there may be times where your low level code is called within the context of a user action.  If you serve specific loggers to specific classes, you'll potentially lose that relevant context information.  If you instead have a func that always checks for user context, when the logger logs it will find context for any call in which context exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had some questions about the DI process but @SteveWilkes ended up helping me on my question comments. I'll use your idea though, a very nice approach to this situation.